# Rewriting my wordpress urls to become legacy urls

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

For a valid reason, I need to rewrite all the urls of my wordpress 'pages' to work as legacy urls.

So for example, when someone enters

`www.mysite.com/contact_us` I want to serve up the page thats sitting on my wordpress as `/contact-us/ but keep the url intact as contact_us

Currently my wordpress permalinks have been set to custom structure, which gives me the following in my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can someone please show me how to add in a rule to rewrite the above. I have loads of urls to do but an example will be a huge help here. Thanks.

I've tried adding

`ReWriteRule ^contact_us$ /contact-us/`, but i just get a 404 on the /contact_us url.

Comment: what happens when you directly enter `www.mysite.com/contact-us/` in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've sussed it: I have just rewritten it to the raw page url. I found the raw url by either turning off permalink rewriting, or by hovering over the view anchor for the specific page, in order to obtain the correct page_id value.

```
RewriteRule ^contact_us/$ /?page_id=101 [L]
RewriteRule ^apply_now/$ /?page_id=41 [L]
```